# abi difference on linux/amd64 C vs C++

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc

I have `C` library with such API:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
struct Foo {
    void *p;
    int len;
};

struct Foo f(void *opaque, int param);
void foo_free(struct Foo *);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

to simplify my `C++` life I decide do simple thing:

```
 struct Foo {
    void *p;
    int len;
#ifdef __cplusplus
    ~Foo() { foo_free(this); }
#endif
};
```

And after that things become crazy: for example if I call
`f(0xfffeeea0, 40)` in `C++`, then on `C` side I got `0x7fff905d2050 -69984`:

assember without destructor:

```
   0x000055555555467a <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x000055555555467b <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x000055555555467e <+4>: sub    $0x10,%rsp
   0x0000555555554682 <+8>: mov    $0x28,%esi
   0x0000555555554687 <+13>:    mov    $0xfffeeea0,%edi
   0x000055555555468c <+18>:    callq  0x5555555546a0 <f>
   0x0000555555554691 <+23>:    mov    %rax,-0x10(%rbp)
   0x0000555555554695 <+27>:    mov    %rdx,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x0000555555554699 <+31>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x000055555555469e <+36>:    leaveq 
   0x000055555555469f <+37>:    retq
```

assember with destructor:

```
   0x00000000000006da <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x00000000000006db <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x00000000000006de <+4>: sub    $0x20,%rsp
   0x00000000000006e2 <+8>: mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
   0x00000000000006eb <+17>:    mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x00000000000006ef <+21>:    xor    %eax,%eax
   0x00000000000006f1 <+23>:    lea    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
   0x00000000000006f5 <+27>:    mov    $0x28,%edx
   0x00000000000006fa <+32>:    mov    $0xfffeeea0,%esi
   0x00000000000006ff <+37>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x0000000000000702 <+40>:    callq  0x739 <f>
   0x0000000000000707 <+45>:    lea    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
   0x000000000000070b <+49>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x000000000000070e <+52>:    callq  0x72e <Foo::~Foo()>
   0x0000000000000713 <+57>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000000000000718 <+62>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rcx
   0x000000000000071c <+66>:    xor    %fs:0x28,%rcx
   0x0000000000000725 <+75>:    je     0x72c <main()+82>
   0x0000000000000727 <+77>:    callq  0x5c0 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
   0x000000000000072c <+82>:    leaveq 
   0x000000000000072d <+83>:    retq
```

I wonder what is going on?
I can understand why compiler should handle return in different
way, but why it moves arguments in different registers `%esi` vs `%edi`.

For clearness I understand that I do wrong thing, and I rewrite code with
some kind of smart pointers instead without touching real `Foo`.
But I wonder how ABI of `c++` and `c` works in this particular case.

full example:

```
//test.cpp
extern "C" {
    struct Foo {
        void *p;
        int len;
        ~Foo() {/*call free*/}
    };

    struct Foo f(void *opaque, int param);
}

int main()
{
    auto foo = f(reinterpret_cast<void *>(0xfffeeea0), 40);
}

//test.c
#include <stdio.h>

struct Foo {
    void *p;
    int len;
};

struct Foo f(void *opaque, int param)
{
    printf("!!! %p %d\n", opaque, param);
    struct Foo ret = {0, 0};    
    return ret;
}
#makefile:
prog: test.cpp test.c
    gcc -Wall -ggdb -std=c11 -c -o test.c.o test.c
    g++ -Wall -ggdb -std=c++11 -o $@ test.cpp test.c.o
    ./prog
```

Comment: I recommend removing the C and Linux tags.  Member functions are not C.  There are no calls to the Linux OS.

Comment: IIRC c++ has a hidden "this" parameter

Comment: @melpomene I add full code at the end.

Comment: @technosaurus But I call not member function

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Windows ABI x64 may different for calling C/C++ functions, that is why I add linux tag. And also question about c/c++ cooperation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first version of your code (no destructor), we have:

```
// allocate 16 bytes on the stack (for a Foo instance)
sub    $0x10,%rsp

// load two (constant) arguments into %edi and %esi
mov    $0x28,%esi
mov    $0xfffeeea0,%edi

// call f
callq  0x5555555546a0 <f>

// a 2-word struct was returned by value (in %rax/%rdx).
// move the values to the corresponding slots on the stack
mov    %rax,-0x10(%rbp)
mov    %rdx,-0x8(%rbp)
```

In the second version (with a destructor):

```
// load address of Foo instance into %rax
lea    -0x20(%rbp),%rax

// load three arguments:
//  - 40 in %edx
//  - 0xfffeeea0 in %esi
//  - &foo in %rdi
mov    $0x28,%edx
mov    $0xfffeeea0,%esi
mov    %rax,%rdi

// ... and call f
callq  0x739 <f>

// ignore f's return value; load &foo into %rax again
lea    -0x20(%rbp),%rax

// call ~Foo on &foo
mov    %rax,%rdi
callq  0x72e <Foo::~Foo()>
```

My guess is that without a destructor the struct is treated like a plain 2-word tuple and returned by value.

But with a destructor the compiler assumes it can't just copy the member values around, so it transforms the struct return value into a hidden pointer argument:

```
struct Foo f(void *opaque, int param);

// actually implemented as:
void f(struct Foo *_hidden, void *opaque, int param);
```

Normally `f` would then take care of writing the return value into `*_hidden`.

Because the caller and the implementer of the function see a different return type, they disagree about the number of parameters the function actually has. The C++ code passes 3 arguments, but the C code only looks at two of them. It misinterprets the address of the `Foo` instance as the `opaque` pointer, and what was supposed to be the `opaque` pointer ends up in `param`.

In other words, the presence of a destructor means `Foo` is no longer a POD type, which inhibits simple return-by-value through registers.